# Linear program with norm constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

It is straightforward to convert the following optimization problem to a linear program by defining some appropriate variables.
$$\max_w z^{\top}w \qquad \text{s.t.} \qquad Aw \leq b, \lVert w\rVert_1 \leq l$$

I was wondering if I can also convert the following problem to a linear program.
$$\max_w z^{\top}w \qquad \text{s.t.} \qquad Aw \leq b, \lVert Qw - v\rVert_1 \leq l$$
Here $Q$ is a fat matrix with full row rank. By fat I mean it has way more columns than rows.

Comment: Use the same trick with $\tilde w_i = e_i^TQw -v_i$...

Comment: @user251257 and what do I substitute for $w$ in the objective and the other constraint?

Comment: why changing them?

Comment: @user251257 So I append $\tilde{w}$ (its negative and positive parts actually) to $w$ and link them via $\tilde{w}^+ - \tilde{w}^- = Qw - v$?

Comment: for example. It depends on the trick you want to apply.

Comment: @user251257 Could you perhaps mention other tricks?

Comment: $\tilde w \ge \pm Qw - v$ and $e^T \tilde w \le l$

Comment: @user251257 Thanks!